# Pressing the back button after editing a question only refreshes the edit page

Tags: bug, questions, edits, firefox, history

This is a navigation bug in Stack Overflow. I go to my user page, and I click on the "Questions" tab.

---

[image]

---

I click on a question, I edit that question, and I try to return to my user page.

---

[image]

---

I press the back button several times and I keep getting redirected back to the question that I edited.

---

[image] Click!

[image] Click!

[image] Click!

---

In my browser's history, it looks like a new entry generates every time I click the back button.

---

[image]

---

In order to get back to my user page, I have to hold the back button until a list appears. I click on my user page.

Comment: Sounds like you're hitting the good old post-get redirect. I wouldn't go as far as calling that a bug, just an artifact of the web that nowadays is usually circumvented by posting through ajax.

Comment: I didn't checked my browser history but I got the same bug every time I edit some question...