# Having to press the back button twice to go back from a question to the previous page after editing a question

Tags: bug, edits, navigation

For a few days now I've noticed that I have to press the back button, or the backspace key, twice to return from a question I edited to the previous page.
The URL doesn't change at all, but for some reason an edit doesn't refresh the page but navigates you to the question again. This happens when you either make an edit, or cancel the edit.

Using FireFox 65.0.2 (without extensions) on MacOS 10.14.5

This can't be reproduced on Meta sites (MSO, MSE).

Edit:
It also happens when revisiting a question I have edited previously (after restarting FF completely)

Here is a screenshot of what happens if I open a question I edited previously.

[image]

Edit2: Some possible warnings that might be related from the browser console (in dutch unfortunately)

> Content Security Policy: ‘x-frame-options’ wordt genegeerd vanwege ‘frame-ancestors’-instructie.

where "wordt genegeerd vanwege" translates to: Is being ignored because of

And

> Er is een niet-gebalanceerde structuur geschreven door gebruik van document.write(), waardoor gegevens van het netwerk opnieuw worden geparset. Voor meer informatie, zie https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Optimizing_Your_Pages_for_Speculative_Parsing

from `view-source:https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/safeframe/1-0-35/html/container.html`

Which translates to something like: There is a non-balanced structure written because of the use of document.write(), this caused re-parsing of data from the network.

Edit 3:
A dump of all post/get/XHR requests when doing the following:

- Click the edit button
- Make an edit to the tags
- Save the edit
- Push the back button twice

(All formatted as code to reduce size in the question)

```
XHRGEThttps://stackoverflow.com/posts/57220309/edit-inline?_=1564145083277
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 112ms]

XHRPOSThttps://stackoverflow.com/posts/validate-body
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 105ms]

XHRGEThttps://stackoverflow.com/api/tags/langdiv?tags=excel+vba&_=1564145083278
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 101ms]

XHRGEThttps://stackoverflow.com/posts/new-tags-warning?tags=excel+vba&_=1564145083279
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 95ms]

XHRPOSThttps://stackoverflow.com/posts/57220309/edit-submit/3d40f164-3dc0-4165-8f93-3988b7c96276
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 151ms]

GEThttps://www.gravatar.com/avatar/7d0c940ad90baf5f93d7ab07933d2e17?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG
[HTTP/2.0 304 Not Modified 12ms]

GEThttps://dt.adsafeprotected.com/dt?advEntityId=292726&asId=82ba80e0-3d76-f98e-c6ee-29c1189679c6&tv={c:jtS39E,pingTime:30,time:33450,type:p,clog:[{piv:100,vs:i,r:,w:300,h:250,t:47},{piv:29,vs:o,r:l,t:7408},{piv:0,t:7509},{piv:40,t:8511},{piv:100,vs:i,r:,t:9027}],es:0,sc:1,ha:1,gm:0,slTimes:{i:31832,o:1618,n:0,pp:0,pm:0},slEvents:[{sl:i,t:46,wc:0.23.1920.1010,ac:1261.705.300.250,am:i,cc:1261.705.300.250,piv:100,obst:0,th:0,reas:,bkn:{piv:[7389~100],as:[7389~300.250]}},{sl:o,t:7408,wc:0.23.1920.1010,ac:1261.-128.300.250,am:i,cc:1261.-128.300.250,piv:40,obst:0,th:0,reas:l,bkn:{piv:[102~25,1001~0,516~30],as:[1619~300.250]}},{sl:i,t:9026,wc:0.23.1920.1010,ac:1261.653.300.250,am:i,cc:1261.653.300.250,piv:100,obst:0,th:0,reas:,bkn:{piv:[24424~100],as:[24425~300.250]}}],slEventCount:3,em:true,fr:false,e:,tt:rjss,dtt:307,fm:rxkJntu+11*.292726-36993954|111,idMap:11*,rend:1,renddet:XIFRAME.qs.dr,rmeas:1}&br=g
[HTTP/1.1 200 OK 488ms]

GEThttps://dt.adsafeprotected.com/dt?advEntityId=292726&asId=82ba80e0-3d76-f98e-c6ee-29c1189679c6&tv={c:jtS733,pingTime:45,time:48417,type:p,clog:[{piv:100,vs:i,r:,w:300,h:250,t:47},{piv:29,vs:o,r:l,t:7408},{piv:0,t:7509},{piv:40,t:8511},{piv:100,vs:i,r:,t:9027}],es:0,sc:1,ha:1,gm:0,slTimes:{i:46799,o:1618,n:0,pp:0,pm:0},slEvents:[{sl:i,t:46,wc:0.23.1920.1010,ac:1261.705.300.250,am:i,cc:1261.705.300.250,piv:100,obst:0,th:0,reas:,bkn:{piv:[7389~100],as:[7389~300.250]}},{sl:o,t:7408,wc:0.23.1920.1010,ac:1261.-128.300.250,am:i,cc:1261.-128.300.250,piv:40,obst:0,th:0,reas:l,bkn:{piv:[102~25,1001~0,516~30],as:[1619~300.250]}},{sl:i,t:9026,wc:0.23.1920.1010,ac:1261.653.300.250,am:i,cc:1261.653.300.250,piv:100,obst:0,th:0,reas:,bkn:{piv:[39391~100],as:[39391~300.250]}}],slEventCount:3,em:true,fr:false,e:,tt:rjss,dtt:304,fm:rxkJntu+11*.292726-36993954|111,idMap:11*,rend:1,renddet:XIFRAME.qs.dr,rmeas:1}&br=g
[HTTP/1.1 200 OK 449ms]

GEThttps://dt.adsafeprotected.com/dt?advEntityId=292726&asId=82ba80e0-3d76-f98e-c6ee-29c1189679c6&tv={c:jtSaIj,pingTime:-1,time:62507,type:u,clog:[{piv:100,vs:i,r:,w:300,h:250,t:47},{piv:29,vs:o,r:l,t:7408},{piv:0,t:7509},{piv:40,t:8511},{piv:100,vs:i,r:,t:9027}],ndt:8,es:0,sc:1,ha:1,gm:0,slTimes:{i:60889,o:1618,n:0,pp:0,pm:0},slEvents:[{sl:i,t:46,wc:0.23.1920.1010,ac:1261.705.300.250,am:i,cc:1261.705.300.250,piv:100,obst:0,th:0,reas:,bkn:{piv:[7389~100],as:[7389~300.250]}},{sl:o,t:7408,wc:0.23.1920.1010,ac:1261.-128.300.250,am:i,cc:1261.-128.300.250,piv:40,obst:0,th:0,reas:l,bkn:{piv:[102~25,1001~0,516~30],as:[1619~300.250]}},{sl:i,t:9026,wc:0.23.1920.1010,ac:1261.653.300.250,am:i,cc:1261.653.300.250,piv:100,obst:0,th:0,reas:,bkn:{piv:[53480~100],as:[53480~300.250]}}],slEventCount:3,em:true,fr:false,e:,tt:rjss,dtt:277,fm:rxkJntu+11*.292726-36993954|111,idMap:11*,rend:1,renddet:XIFRAME.qs.dr,rmeas:1,lt:1}&br=g
GEThttps://stackoverflow.com/
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/activeview?avi=BJ9z8vPU6Xcv4NtXwgAfP562wBQCn_JvhwQkAABABOAHIAQngBAOgBkzSCAcIgOGAEBABwhMGGMmQsoID,BWoLSvPU6XbDFNdXwgAfP562wBebG-cNFAAAAEAEgic7ISTgAWIK_rY6DBGCR5IeF7BeyARFzdGFja292ZXJmbG93LmNvbboBCWdmcF9pbWFnZcgBCdoBZGh0dHBzOi8vc3RhY2tvdmVyZmxvdy5jb20vcXVlc3Rpb25zLzU3MjIwMzA5L2hhbmRsaW5nLW9mLWRpZmZlcmVudC12YXJpYXRpb25zLW9mLWEtc2luZ2xlLXVzZXItaW5wdXSYAqQcwAIC4AIA6gIuLzI0ODQyNDE3Ny9zdGFja292ZXJmbG93LmNvbS9zYi9xdWVzdGlvbi1wYWdlc_gCgtIekAPIBpgD4AOoAwHgBAHSBQYQuNCMgROQBgGgBjuoB_PRG9gHAOAHC_IHAiAB0ggJCIDhgBAQARgN&cid=CAASBORo0Og&adk=228937067&tt=62377&bs=1905%2C914&mtos=53366,53366,53366,53366,54195&tos=58811,0,0,0,829&p=76.51666259765625,1260.5,326.51666259765625,1560.5&mcvt=53366&rs=3&ht=0&tfs=1925&tls=62392&mc=1&lte=1&bas=0&bac=0&avms=nio&niot_obs=11&niot_cbk=27&md=2&rst=1564145085253&dlt=383&rpt=2694&isd=0&msd=1296&lm=2&oseid=3&xdi=0&roio=1&ps=1905%2C2210&ss=1920%2C1080&pt=15&bin=1&deb=1-1-1-277-604-16-641-587&tvt=62380&r=u&id=osdtos&vs=4&uc=589&upc=11&tgt=DIV&cl=1&cec=1&clc=1&cac=1&cd=0x0&itpl=20&v=20190724
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 17ms]

GEThttps://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=b497948c8653
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=b497948c8653
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://cdn.sstatic.net/Shared/stacks.css?v=d0626e33feab
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/primary.css?v=3121fd52eed8
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://cdn.sstatic.net/clc/clc.min.js?v=40b76bc9bf33
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://cdn.sstatic.net/clc/clc.min.js?v=40b76bc9bf33
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://secure.quantserve.com/quant.js
[HTTP/1.1 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://sb.scorecardresearch.com/beacon.js
[HTTP/1.1 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=4f32ecc8f43d
GEThttps://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://secure.quantserve.com/quant.js
[HTTP/1.1 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://sb.scorecardresearch.com/beacon.js
[HTTP/1.1 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/full.en.js?v=b9203662c319
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/full.en.js?v=b9203662c319
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://cdn.sstatic.net/clc/styles/clc.min.css?v=7865eeeae8e2
GEThttps://adservice.google.nl/adsid/integrator.js?domain=stackoverflow.com
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 19ms]

GEThttps://adservice.google.com/adsid/integrator.js?domain=stackoverflow.com
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 18ms]

GEThttps://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/gpt/pubads_impl_2019072201.js
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://sb.scorecardresearch.com/b?c1=2&c2=17440561&ns__t=1564145148847&ns_c=UTF-8&cv=3.1&c8=Stack%20Overflow%20-%20Where%20Developers%20Learn%2C%20Share%2C%20%26%20Build%20Careers&c7=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F&c9=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fusers%2F1481116%2Fluuklag
[HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily 10ms]

GEThttps://rules.quantcount.com/rules-p-c1rF4kxgLUzNc.js
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

POSThttps://csi.gstatic.com/csi?v=2&s=pagead&action=csi_pagead&puid=2~jyk3lmfe&ctx=2&qqid=CMvGpsHO0uMCFVU44Aodz3MLVg&uet=2&met.3=118.2hq_1~118.2i4~115.2io~118.2ki~115.2ll~118.2ne_1~115.2oe~118.2q9_1~115.2r9~118.2ts_1~115.2ug~118.2wr_5~118.2zq_1~118.32k_1~118.35e~118.38d~118.3b9~118.3e9~118.3h4~118.3jy_1~118.3mx_1~118.3r0~118.3tu_1~118.3wp_1~118.3zn_1~118.42h~118.45b~118.485~118.4b2~118.4dy_1~118.4gv~118.4js~118.4mm~118.4pl_1~118.4sg~118.4va~118.4y7~118.510~118.540_1~118.56q~118.59n_1~118.5ch_1~118.5fb~118.5i6_1~118.5la~118.5o7_1~118.5r1~118.5tz~118.5ws~118.5zn_1~118.62m_1~118.65m_1~118.67w_1~118.6ab~118.6d7~118.6g3~118.6iz~118.6lt_1~118.6oo_1~118.6rj_1~118.6ud_1~118.6uv~118.6xf~118.705_1~118.72z~118.75u~118.78r~118.7bl_1~118.7ei~118.7hg~118.7km~118.7n7_1~118.7q1~118.7sv~118.7vs~118.7ym_1~118.81h~118.84a_1~118.874_2~118.8a0~118.8cw~118.8fp~118.8is~118.8li~118.8om~118.8re~118.8u7_4~118.8x2_1~118.8zx_1~118.92v~118.95q~118.98p~118.9bi~118.9ed_1~118.9hb_1~118.9k7_1~118.9n6~118.9q1~118.9sw~118.9vq~118.9yj_1~118.a1g_1~118.a4a~118.a76~118.aa4_1~118.ad2~118.afy_1~118.aiu_1~118.alr~118.aol_1~118.arh~118.aue_1~118.axa_1~118.b05_1~118.b30_1~118.b5w_1~118.b8w~118.bbq~118.bej~118.bhh~118.bkc~118.bna~118.bq4~118.bsw~118.bvr_1~118.byl~118.c1f~118.c4a~118.c74_1~118.ca1~118.cct~118.cfo~118.cij~118.clf_1~118.cog~118.cr7~118.cu4_1~118.cwy~118.czw_1~118.d2t~118.d5p~118.d8n~118.dbg~118.dea~118.dh5_1~118.dk3~118.dmz~118.dpv_1~118.dso_1~118.dvj~118.dyi~118.e1g~118.e4d_1~118.e7c~118.ea6_1~118.ed1~118.efv~118.eiq~118.elk~118.eof~118.erc_1~118.eu9~118.ewy~118.ezs~118.f2n~118.f5l_1~118.f8l~118.fbh~118.feg_1~118.fhb_1~118.fk6~118.fn1~118.fpv_1~118.fss~118.fvn_1~118.fyn~118.g1i_1~118.g4e~118.g79_2~118.ga6_2~118.gd5~118.gg2_1~118.giz_1~118.glx~118.gou~118.grn_2~118.gum~118.gxj~118.h0c~118.h37_1~118.h63~118.h96_1~118.hbw~118.her~118.hhl_1~118.hkg_1~118.hnc~118.hrl~118.hue_1~118.hx8~118.i05~118.i30_1~118.i5v_1~118.i8r~118.ibo~118.iei~118.ihc~118.ik6~118.in1~118.ip5_1~118.irr~118.iuk_1~118.ixm_1~118.j0h~118.j3f~118.j65~118.j93_1~118.jbx~118.jet~118.jht_1~118.jkj~118.jni_1~118.jqa_1~118.jt4_1~118.jvy~118.jyt_1~118.jzf~118.k22_1~118.k4x~118.k7s~118.kb0_1~118.kb1~118.kdn_1~118.kgj~118.kjf~118.km9_2~118.kp4_1~118.ks0_1~118.kux~118.kxr~118.l0p~118.l3g~118.l6c~118.l7v~118.laq~118.ldj~118.lgd_1~118.lj7_1~118.lm5~118.loz~118.lrv~118.lup_1~118.lxn_1~118.m0i_1~118.m3f~118.m68_1~118.m93~118.mc1~118.mey~118.mhr_1~118.mkk~118.mne_1~118.mq9~118.mt2_1~118.mvx_1~118.myr~118.n1n~118.n4m~118.n7i_1~118.naj~118.nd9_2~118.ng4_3~118.niz~118.nlu~118.noq~118.nrl~118.nue~118.nxa~118.o03~118.o2x_1~118.o5u~118.o8p_1~118.obk_1~118.oeg_1~118.ohd~118.oka~118.onc~118.oq1_1~118.osx~118.ovs_1~118.oyn_1~118.p1n~118.p4h~118.p7k~118.pac~118.pdc~118.pg8~118.pj2~118.plx~118.pou~118.prx~118.puu~118.pxv~118.q0p_1~118.q3o~118.q6i~118.q9e_2~118.qce_1~118.qf5~118.qhz_1~118.qkt~118.qns~118.qqo~118.qti~118.qwf~118.qzb_1~118.r29~118.r56~118.r80~118.ray_1~118.rdu~118.rgp~118.rji~118.rmi~118.rpe~118.rsc~118.rva~118.ry6~118.s12~118.s3v_1~118.s6t~118.s9n~118.sck~118.sfi~118.sic~118.slb~118.so7~118.sr1~118.sty~118.swu~118.szq~118.t2j_1~118.t5i_1~118.t8e~118.tba~118.te6_1~118.th1_1~118.tjy~118.tmr~118.tpp~118.tsk_1~118.tvi~118.tyd_1~118.u18~118.u46~118.u73~118.ua0~118.ucu_1~118.ufp_1~118.uim_1~118.ulj~118.uod_1~118.urc~118.uu6~118.uwz_1~118.uzs_1~118.v2o~118.v5g_1~118.v8d~118.vb9~118.ve4_1~118.vh0~118.vjt~118.vmr~118.vps~118.vsn~118.vvg_1~118.vyc~118.w16~118.w40_1~118.w6u~118.w9q~118.wco~118.wfi~118.wic_1~118.wl5_1~118.wo0~118.wqw~118.wtp~118.wwj~118.wzg_1~118.x2b~118.x56_1~118.x81~118.xax~118.xdv~118.xgs~118.xjo~118.xmj~118.xpf_1~118.xsd~118.xv8~118.xy6~118.y11_1~118.y40~118.y6t_1~118.y9q~118.ycq_1~118.yfl~118.yih~118.ylf~118.yoa~118.yr5~118.yu1~118.ywy~118.yzv~118.z2q~118.z5k~118.z8j~118.zbg~118.zef~118.zha~118.zk7~118.zn1_1~118.zpw_1~118.zsu~118.zvs_1~118.zys~118.101r~118.104m~118.107h_1~118.10ac~118.10d9_1~118.10g6~118.10j0~118.10lv~118.10op~118.10rm_1~118.10uj~118.10xh~118.110f~118.1139~118.1165~118.1190~118.11bx_1~118.11er_1~118.11hn_1~118.11ki_1~118.11nd~118.11qa_1~118.11t9~118.11w7~118.11yz_1~118.121t_2~118.124n_1~118.127g~118.12ad_1~118.12d8~118.12g5~118.12j0~118.12lv~118.12ot~118.12rn_1~118.12uh~118.12xe_1~118.130a_1~118.1338~118.1362~118.1390_1~118.13bz~118.13ev~118.13hq~118.13kk~118.13ni~118.13qc~118.13ta~118.13w8~118.13z2~118.141v~118.144q~118.147p_1~118.14al~118.14dh~118.14gd~118.14j9_1~118.14m6~118.14oz_1~118.14ry_1~118.14ut~118.14xq~118.150m~118.153h_1~118.156d_1~118.159a~118.15c4_1~118.15f2~118.15hx_1~118.15kr_1~118.15nq~118.15ql~118.15tj_1~118.15wd~118.15zd~118.1627~118.1655~118.1682_1~118.16b2~118.16dx~118.16gq~118.16jp~118.16mj~118.16pf~118.16sf~118.16va~118.16ya_1~118.1718~118.1747~118.1771_1~118.179w_1~118.17cr_1~118.17fl_1~118.17ij_1~118.17le~118.17oe~118.17ra~118.17u4_1~118.17x2_1~118.17zy~118.182w_1~118.185u~118.188p~118.18bn~118.18eh~118.18he~118.18kb~118.18n8_1~118.18q2_1~118.18sw~118.18vs~118.18yp_1~118.191m~118.194i_1~118.197e~118.19ac~118.19d9_1~118.19g3_1~118.19j1~118.19lv_1~118.19op_1~118.19rl~118.19uf~118.19x9~118.1a04_1~118.1a2y_1~118.1a5u~118.1a8o~118.1abj_1~118.1aec~118.1ahd~118.1ak7~118.1an1~118.1apx~118.1ast~118.1avo~118.1ayj~118.1b1d~118.1b49~118.1b74~118.1ba2~118.1bcy~118.1bfw~118.1biu_1~118.1blo~118.1bon~118.1brl~118.1buk~118.1bxi~118.1c0d_1~118.1c3c~118.1c67~118.1c93~118.1cc0~118.1cey~118.1chv~118.1ckr_1~118.1cnp~118.1cqn&met.1=24.1cst&met.7=CBsYASCIGSiIGTDuJDjmCw~CBsQBiCrGTiIAw~CBsQBiCsGjj0AQ~CCAQBhgBIMAdKMAdMM4eOI4BaLgecM0eeOUEgAEqiAEqsAEBuAED~CBsQBiC3OThi~CBsQBiC4lQE4qgI~CBsQBiDgigI4pQI~CBsQBiDW_wI4kAI~CBsQBiDh7QM
[HTTP/2.0 204 No Content 99ms]

POSThttps://csi.gstatic.com/csi?v=2&s=pagead&action=csi_pagead&puid=3~jyk3mwr7&ctx=2&qqid=CMvGpsHO0uMCFVU44Aodz3MLVg&uet=1&met.3=119.1csw_2&met.1=24.1csy&met.7=CBsQBiC3OThi~CBsQBiC4lQE4qgI~CBsQBiDgigI4pQI~CBsQBiDW_wI4kAI~CBsQBiDh7QM
[HTTP/2.0 204 No Content 97ms]

GEThttps://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/gpt/pubads_impl_2019072201.js
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://qa.sockets.stackexchange.com/
[HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols 283ms]

GEThttps://pixel.quantserve.com/pixel;r=1937945536;rf=0;a=p-c1rF4kxgLUzNc;url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F;ref=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fusers%2F1481116%2Fluuklag;fpan=0;fpa=P0-931083462-1534843630842;ns=0;ce=1;qjs=1;qv=4c19192-20180628134937;cm=;je=0;sr=1920x1080x24;enc=n;dst=1;et=1564145149220;tzo=-120;ogl=type.website%2Curl.https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow%252Ecom%2F%2Csite_name.Stack%20Overflow%2Cimage.https%3A%2F%2Fcdn%252Esstatic%252Enet%2FSites%2Fstackoverflow%2Fimg%2Fapple-touch-icon%402%252Epng%3Fv%3D73d79a8%2Ctitle.Stack%20Overflow%20-%20Where%20Developers%20Learn%252C%20Share%252C%20%26%20Build%20Careers%2Cdescription.Stack%20Overflow%20%7C%20The%20World%E2%80%99s%20Largest%20Online%20Community%20for%20Developers
[HTTP/1.1 200 OK 91ms]

XHRGEThttps://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?gdfp_req=1&pvsid=567337803047026&correlator=2390828633250743&output=json_html&callback=googletag.impl.pubads.callbackProxy1&impl=fifs&json_a=1&eid=21062453%2C21063387&vrg=2019072201&guci=1.2.0.0.2.2.0.0&plat=1%3A1081352%2C2%3A17858568%2C8%3A134250504&sc=1&sfv=1-0-35&ecs=20190726&iu_parts=248424177%2Cstackoverflow.com%2Csb%2Chome-page&enc_prev_ius=%2F0%2F1%2F2%2F3&prev_iu_szs=300x250%7C300x600&fsfs=1&fsbs=1&cust_params=Registered%3Dtrue%26Reputation%3D1500%26Sidebar%3DRight&cookie=ID%3D882ff51a6f98d74b%3AT%3D1560235461%3AS%3DALNI_MZ39Qh4DEnA5c5xfYIqQqcaUkrQ7g&bc=29&abxe=1&lmt=1564137949&dt=1564145149304&dlt=1564145148486&idt=755&frm=20&biw=1905&bih=914&oid=3&adxs=-12245933&adys=-12245933&adks=2451320170&ucis=1&ifi=1&u_tz=120&u_his=18&u_h=1080&u_w=1920&u_ah=1010&u_aw=1920&u_cd=24&u_sd=1&flash=0&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F&ref=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fusers%2F1481116%2Fluuklag&dssz=23&icsg=674&std=23&vis=1&scr_x=0&scr_y=0&psz=300x1796&msz=300x250&ga_vid=219071516.1467104252&ga_sid=1564145149&ga_hid=421833674&fws=128&ohw=0
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 172ms]

GEThttps://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/gpt/pubads_impl_rendering_2019072201.js
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://sb.scorecardresearch.com/b2?c1=2&c2=17440561&ns__t=1564145148847&ns_c=UTF-8&cv=3.1&c8=Stack%20Overflow%20-%20Where%20Developers%20Learn%2C%20Share%2C%20%26%20Build%20Careers&c7=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F&c9=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fusers%2F1481116%2Fluuklag
[HTTP/1.1 204 No Content 11ms]

GEThttps://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/gpt/pubads_impl_rendering_2019072201.js
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/keyboard-shortcuts.en.js?v=8b58dd3b0619
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/keyboard-shortcuts.en.js?v=8b58dd3b0619
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://clc.stackoverflow.com/markup.js?omni=AojYeQXHEdcIcmkYAAAAAAACAAAAAQAAAAMAAAAAAHXYE2OpsBgjMck&zc=24&pf=8&lw=789
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 151ms]

GEThttps://tpc.googlesyndication.com/safeframe/1-0-35/html/container.html
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://www.googletagservices.com/activeview/js/current/osd.js?cb=%2Fr20100101
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

POSThttps://www.google-analytics.com/r/collect
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 13ms]

GEThttps://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/xbbe/pixel?d=CIkCEIuDmgEY9uXLWDAB&v=APEucNX2uyhJ7ZrFoWtG1EsbdY4HrlcekLUjuC79hsgh6vZ6LWbQcgAf_ojDNDs5et9UhkkEVYB3k62ppWwu7Ale7ZFwKqhkwWF9JoWia6EFTjsetabuRbq5p4p2jLTVEvD0wppjnL4tFXOqjnfr-h5Q5Vv7-MNKw7bZ9aHq1or-HdFJDsx-DeU
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 15ms]

GEThttps://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/dbm/ad?dbm_c=AKAmf-CZTElUkIRjPKEp6YqEq4dItslRWFDWI1gsfjMBV2ekefhyuxC7k-39e8EOCz7-Zj9HP1mvMQbCJrOlHQRatcXjQ9cSAg&dbm_d=AKAmf-CSqbsKP7DADj15yL4ddRuElyOxIIl2y7653TUNKl6adxc3ywBgTPbGdo9X8T46S60-djVF5W23WEfUksPRkxe7Sawu_luArFknhXSl6mRoJ3UhYGPLfYhdOmTSJV89Qa8gWUDSSTQEe80nnBsnPTqReSNqTob-S2_Ns8eddjIt_CgDMlNU6uZRqNZHPa09GDxPpZRIq4i9fnF6qGlD4LsScW93ATP9ukvnvf-JzsMjrHE-xx3RwggTWvihsbNZjcqVglkWoxXF9L3u8fulKFuHZCF4cLl0yzLKpQPQN2XZDoTyMBAmtn3H_yEXbydiFIknEGvjwsbeCIJRPDHNF4PaYSrl50YO7CA2nCogsMiY340JopyJzHoSNWcn20R6SYYfWAAddF8YpdHfFEG0xqP53DQA6IIbnRUspLazFbnq2omIx0ib0OaHg6dhxBE5D3OYHUFhGjwUQDosDAxS_w6PoWKXkp7m8n1Py6QcP-mIYQZKfWWMnONSRTFT-PFuOqQcGLQQCRg5L8JEe0lPZFoheNfnp_2fMtEc0BqX3jdQuw8wDFBTlw0FhJV4i5W1TabWuX1i73DrlcvgyjI9BCZtjM2DGClCa5shJ6rC5V76vCS9nVrT_7dIw1BHyYDiGKhwKVQBTM1vdrFtS5LycU1TOfozVIGVkwnd4lYwZ1Sp0LOYXTze7ls0X9spIrr2jynHpkYOj198D4RHiIKxgDqR3WsXcJRi4D3G7r8chpYTzbT_oXImX5fE7ZntyM4MnbQVDmg72x53YS2OT482tP2D2FY-sRKr7moKn1Qfddj-3mmg0io6aNxG5tEFmAqKDcUKg90XW8jHSepGVEkzLFTH4EeV_uomKtcKQBCBlhEQ37JRE8_ysILYmEp68ys10aRoOW_U2IO3daqhDmwyTji_Xu4QxMn6f4XqMy4pbWsUgVzDnzT03Osd2z5WF5aMX5JyjOsJza1LZc03sQB9OM25M14JPTcFDsiWDYo4nYbuF2U1m4ZHvqztTakqyO4JwwYawC47YURF7ZdJBbTwDk-mVR-oZf0ozS6Lk7Nt8_PIeFwlkgEHOaXzmrU6Ww0u-Fd2OKf06A2lhpC8GMLW9okMzaE6Nak9gCfaosp7C9byyvAUlg3zde6ImmauRb-cyUqsyIuSkim74-hv-_zVkui6IwJtY31Nu_KZVW0d2-GHLhnDwd369s4d9d1Oq-TASeJy2fcahqF6pkmonOq5BXjI9BJkB-_lLaTZ62dKdkH88o9vqCneZ9qYWDUdoCa7oGXqFTMECHNAuq_IsMcIZmlQc1FN1t5ylpa_6YelvZzT6xSFdQWWDnSU57riVCKMHUGsunrdTLg8QYXIppEC9fWmSfGhjk-LSB-M2yf4kJVeO6abNVCtUB9zQ-kjk7OG_U29QBXT7NBSPfXOEemHGsKXJcPvj9jbKyNqmhLnYjT71DTv8XUfli-bGkq-whOzNBboBE5QQMoakBZprOkow_fa3GsAZ63HCzwn4tvzLXuL8ivzXyPTpMStJnwrKvANepKTI2xhOrkwl3-ypUrGrG96ccTdn0pjLVyqe80Ttt2GtaXoVu5Y5wjiZRVYboHFAiddFbzfm25ihNcp7fotDARY7Sv4AJx_Vem1qLS7YL0vGezHPqFWIqi4QZREr_VOBoynagS_5VW8sPE3Jnpd4TFuZGmhl8uEzbqyBGU1BAnUgEaTyNd6K6uexfalDg5SeJ8Y0RsfpnmF0brnvszTH4AqzLC_qj_vo9eF7X6Sp77mG_4Pg3tjKzKweyT3gl5dAWIz19bVlGnEmVNGwR1p74CfzDOGVPPu6inbmK6qtTe0hfM909XCry-igcwPKtUoXlZR-D50_03cmy2EKA1f5YN3E5GdUHpp4z2NkFG_t3K4KM1lW7wk0DUp-zSP902taF9umgaE70CNp7logU6IcivbnJvv_8ErfNsEKj9vrZ8j6C0l2dMorn7RoKt0WOZtDdGMN1WS8LXu132oeXu22Hp3QRsvTadNlVfL5cTTSP-Xz2NFKRZcv0Gvl7cvsJQk0YMT7LxXq_hwEgo6grw-GEQpIRNvWJlBXNavpnr0snYwmLF4zkvazpwAWwsIH6yqzDwt22xneNHuSzpc8pIByeouKs6x05oyyNb9xKRUjfmepjzvuovmdR5YjKr5d4EV5yqlCRi31TSaeXA1H32GXgQNjw7zI_scEtDJnWQ3RJju3VrLEb4wSlA2IcjrtVilKd6saSSm_YVv2udImvrWZ9N7LqUEO9OUG3JJlsMWxEhho6Dq9Dc&cid=CAASBORokPQ
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 46ms]

GEThttps://fw.adsafeprotected.com/rjss/bgd/292726/36993954/xbbe/creative/adj?p=APEucNWxbSLlZpZR_5kk6mld9KwbLbRONvsVLuVvlEB6q-FAVEw5iyQ&d=CkkAoCZ_4I1y4jHgHRtBBwHkQLZGk5W3DR3PFlhbNZHNu0vIWaHtdQMOIuIIfgE5FhAURex1eY1hTNK6iNf5fiGeC222sSsBPUOxEtkQAKAmf-B7geQzcgrbORpj0NUepgNotWMspubeV0xNu-e5QSm_HMKUbA3me_3jJWbAUgiIV28nyWJyc470kkjQNL4-ztqPtB0ZCTaHnk_6LDr-2_BknKWylfkJw-4k7U1d3IwxuZoj3hqoPxX85GMKvPw6o5t6ty4wYNuL1oE4XAB0gKDh3U5yjo8HN7N8LGFNJl57RhtsKk37d0aRt37DZHjWeHeXXvy7FXxczIW_z6VtumJjmvq7Pk_OpjIw92tI7-pZ5bQ99K0oWmHa4S9IFmpYWRB1O_OqieXM9uVdNHwGZKgN8uUHkgjfXHSlzhgyLIXBN0G2Mhjq2FLQHqBcmEpwHZRiPOjJDGNuWUcTMlFgtz4kAZEIZgp5IyvQ9hAzPgdoJhMaVolZSH94S1kKigzKSeSFGoSbtSpuv3pAgNe3f7P0GiS-gpaZKmj85RZLo-nrV6xg2w2Fivj1-QEX69s1M4tcSuetDIhqxotNcjW1zYWgx1kT3pDylHxVITxfnU_aKgYQec72apSPqC1XYJh8mBl82p5GEt-cWrekyJR4MPNqg7AdKTWJ96b_77U8fL2QejIw85XQR2QXjRkNJcrMn3EmeEfByGiNSyOxiIWoU9nnDCtUUzo0WRRXBLYeOBHDCPh654L065gLNt1FBXALQdjc0fUWnElcXi-RRj1oiwj9TUWzmkuZGYpRXhMoRZRMii2uUtqpZC01WIrVPwzP-GdAGoew8KhB1ZsQveHprSxqIq-_9pB_q6lJYVLXameHgaTJLzVaU0dEVVOUNcOkI0VO1k3MWcHZS-Fe0MRYGrDm8ExWX3UgwVndnEMFogBG6FEaZXcOLZArOT5OS-0uzZYsUcDVCOdDW_2Vn2xywkfeTUJXPZSFvek0SA-LNBBiVAy2XvZgh8KD-oLtIJyr3TqCkC0_Fm4rAS0tqjOpkpui_cYZR4z9fmvQelmMv9-rDvFgeAx5zcEuP5QtHKa-nMViwgu08TvTt_e3wQGbadAQYrirIT-aAkYmNhQiuGQiw5x99y2mArxSiQ7oZ4p3RI7UwOEiqNsIOrPeLhcQ4u2ll63ZJeNMfOLVKHQ18OFCaetmuR29x1zk3kdVV5ChAHPw5UO6JLAmP3RasePKLfYREF3eqlijkdpgU2-g42KElQFLTmaVMeZxA32hO0ZfqAVLQQ7ornHNjwqFYoE7__JdHDuluMo1mLJ2ftAer3posWD1lgyKxrWIBaSZptUwHO2LPmUkXNLeRsYl4zwWqsv3rMPhvmllpOMWLefJKMvTBrrXilqeQf3Y1VWztOKO-QG8OkkXq3HZ4bAdiSx0xkiGe6nt4LnhpmqdzmQzZ-8IGrfRuLpgEEhFM0tcUfqyroXT-Wdzu7s1A9CMHYTj0nYLvGlKse71PU3U8LZeMjQa9m9xxl6_Hh4n7oCyTNJRzK4dry83OUkA5jfLpzm1bRUlLWrkG1_l5A-iYd5NlRI-a9CftiQSJdqmvGUPbWfFOUHke0MgeqyDR5Tot7ZDZXJfVFghRhVb77cGOfHqkIxhNjZefwwKIdhVf41lNYb_DYvhajhfyMsZgxJLEWeK6aHNghRQ3vAuQ3XQ-P-pbyIGa1Tfkvwp6SRCMZ6D4Z4pO3H70xUZZuNtDHOlirb6gi4mYSRssTiUg_1r1BdiLLoX9h4tViWJYh8q69S_LNCBO8NBdam4nqFoPJuBaWUC2y1wT2q1IrOzFRzurnCXS46i4-Gzbnx4xzpCFVuvSwKRKp_KZR1n0MPvIpw8zloYUELh3cpzdodMcrYm_sdS3JaK4doxVoZfHWdZQBdQiOm0GQQCoOCcn6Lr3K5X5aZB_D7Gv94zDNJ53ESM7FtK4WPydj6ilA8mfiRD-ISmh28vVDlSHFg59kZ-QVZd0jqpdmkkcFpWSDONZyC3IJCIJLQAZgq-9rXiK1HGkI1ljPkSvDfOHc0N0WdTtxo6OaFdM1OuJ8pqT6ByVsDWlbPxj5fS1vnG1UHubM6aTIiKyAb2UgRphtfauSIebYJHii1ywM-Vngsrb4VZC6Irhgs0GZ5UtibzCK9_z3UcL7mKJLAJr5L69xzOTdvE0m85m7Qay6MlsPL7VQKWEdq5TjOegtxQ3hWaHc7AYDS_MigjhmYvm01_tO3Zexrtbj52OBT-h3xRZawGtjshSh7MqjhJYBll7AYmXU9h_gi01gieEkZndxD3RfdHIzej6elLUsua4x7OvK88IIOlFrf3yCue50p3LgB_NFNFSIo_Dj-jlK5qXm1r9zk6hILZ3ZELTYbG1DgEfzshFDq6y4gCYoK7QTwhs0ou_IQdB133gg0_rGt5tTUvlH6rIn3n9HxzeeUrSXWDPq3AK86IG-dVhZvfWOlOkQllacwlAO7zbyldKbI08vPuEdWVAfTzX1KFFlEyiXH831kyPM2yn-h1JmdVo6ISduwHJO8iJq31mgAE8kkLYetqHHpOpWFhiVWYITQegVtyOJWIUBxhB3okjOyIjNvNaHw48e3XO9iGErUy3RJe_0--UVI1ovJW1FIN7in4Heac_18po8mRAIi6Y7mI3jHL66UGlSAKNipoUNtXxzskOEGyLr2WatcO9jvXhS2r8EB-jX7hTCNUqKj9zcwy77YIlpdxKH_BiTROOhT4p0CuXCfskKhtnMcF1h2nHYvX4sdzG7N2jWofYr7iEQCFvaMmVNf7UGz5a6G7Kkyyur424pSoJPXvA_MVHZa9F0NR26KcktQzsck1tnTFAplW9JLqYeMt3xKJhLTYbD85fXL8htaV38E_Bsq_yadYmYkCD7kO-DCIoyAjuN6v6mkSAemvWoGzktaECHIlhDpGNj9HqlQ1iMFtdxoICAASBORokPRgAQ&xfc=https://adclick.g.doubleclick.net/pcs/click%3Fxai%3DAKAOjstE8NxB_LLXd-cCsaacSaM7uSPZZAT3C3rw050Sv_I8gOl5K47ySZMgKqBMc1RYFH0N_EtFKvx5yCW37isNHZYj1xaF1oe881WCUcxcC1EOu3oSkf2aEqe4LX_5xQejAPQHb73WlznnxYvMMs2DJHopvqbHFOWlfyxH5153QtKH7GQGJNOvPaCGO1172emoD9V9eui-I6Mg_HWTEzep_WDAc_BYRPYzeUvSA_KOBYB_H0fFDrHBn5XUyI7QXEly3WS9glB_E5C8z-foLv8I8HXcp1qwywTPq8P-Jw%26sai%3DAMfl-YQlFpfICcJmlUjVYIGOy6U8IBAzqghnMQh1JPN_vYx7d_MZjIYoE9r245rMxQkAzNGxOnN58J9lEwUnei5_U0xB7tfxXA7_X_g10enTjA%26sig%3DCg0ArKJSzDZ5QRnF_PyqEAE%26urlfix%3D1%26adurl%3D
[HTTP/1.1 200 OK 114ms]

GEThttps://www.googletagservices.com/activeview/js/current/osd_listener.js?cache=r20110914
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://tpc.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/r20190724/r20110914/client/qs_click_protection.js
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://www.googletagservices.com/activeview/js/current/osd.js?cb=%2Fr20100101
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://www.googletagservices.com/activeview/js/current/osd_listener.js?cache=r20110914
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://tpc.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/r20190724/r20110914/client/qs_click_protection.js
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://clc.stackoverflow.com/impression.gif?an=4yp9x2RwXPC6h-YJbx8_JkaBT5cSS1Ptg-6zvzXNZvzodyfgRCADM0PPBgaGBntGRgam2Uz3TnD938bft0ICKJ5y4MC3Bsve0Ld2jGwFlSUZ-XnSTPPb-FpuC_07Iy3PzMB0YMuMRZaBYlfs9O2ZC9UZkABL3BImMEMCiLkYWOWbmcFceSBmYmc9wnLoudxkZTs3dQA&md=285
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 93ms]

GEThttps://fw.adsafeprotected.com/rfw/bgd/292726/36993954/xbbe/creative/adj?p=APEucNWxbSLlZpZR_5kk6mld9KwbLbRONvsVLuVvlEB6q-FAVEw5iyQ&d=CkkAoCZ_4I1y4jHgHRtBBwHkQLZGk5W3DR3PFlhbNZHNu0vIWaHtdQMOIuIIfgE5FhAURex1eY1hTNK6iNf5fiGeC222sSsBPUOxEtkQAKAmf-B7geQzcgrbORpj0NUepgNotWMspubeV0xNu-e5QSm_HMKUbA3me_3jJWbAUgiIV28nyWJyc470kkjQNL4-ztqPtB0ZCTaHnk_6LDr-2_BknKWylfkJw-4k7U1d3IwxuZoj3hqoPxX85GMKvPw6o5t6ty4wYNuL1oE4XAB0gKDh3U5yjo8HN7N8LGFNJl57RhtsKk37d0aRt37DZHjWeHeXXvy7FXxczIW_z6VtumJjmvq7Pk_OpjIw92tI7-pZ5bQ99K0oWmHa4S9IFmpYWRB1O_OqieXM9uVdNHwGZKgN8uUHkgjfXHSlzhgyLIXBN0G2Mhjq2FLQHqBcmEpwHZRiPOjJDGNuWUcTMlFgtz4kAZEIZgp5IyvQ9hAzPgdoJhMaVolZSH94S1kKigzKSeSFGoSbtSpuv3pAgNe3f7P0GiS-gpaZKmj85RZLo-nrV6xg2w2Fivj1-QEX69s1M4tcSuetDIhqxotNcjW1zYWgx1kT3pDylHxVITxfnU_aKgYQec72apSPqC1XYJh8mBl82p5GEt-cWrekyJR4MPNqg7AdKTWJ96b_77U8fL2QejIw85XQR2QXjRkNJcrMn3EmeEfByGiNSyOxiIWoU9nnDCtUUzo0WRRXBLYeOBHDCPh654L065gLNt1FBXALQdjc0fUWnElcXi-RRj1oiwj9TUWzmkuZGYpRXhMoRZRMii2uUtqpZC01WIrVPwzP-GdAGoew8KhB1ZsQveHprSxqIq-_9pB_q6lJYVLXameHgaTJLzVaU0dEVVOUNcOkI0VO1k3MWcHZS-Fe0MRYGrDm8ExWX3UgwVndnEMFogBG6FEaZXcOLZArOT5OS-0uzZYsUcDVCOdDW_2Vn2xywkfeTUJXPZSFvek0SA-LNBBiVAy2XvZgh8KD-oLtIJyr3TqCkC0_Fm4rAS0tqjOpkpui_cYZR4z9fmvQelmMv9-rDvFgeAx5zcEuP5QtHKa-nMViwgu08TvTt_e3wQGbadAQYrirIT-aAkYmNhQiuGQiw5x99y2mArxSiQ7oZ4p3RI7UwOEiqNsIOrPeLhcQ4u2ll63ZJeNMfOLVKHQ18OFCaetmuR29x1zk3kdVV5ChAHPw5UO6JLAmP3RasePKLfYREF3eqlijkdpgU2-g42KElQFLTmaVMeZxA32hO0ZfqAVLQQ7ornHNjwqFYoE7__JdHDuluMo1mLJ2ftAer3posWD1lgyKxrWIBaSZptUwHO2LPmUkXNLeRsYl4zwWqsv3rMPhvmllpOMWLefJKMvTBrrXilqeQf3Y1VWztOKO-QG8OkkXq3HZ4bAdiSx0xkiGe6nt4LnhpmqdzmQzZ-8IGrfRuLpgEEhFM0tcUfqyroXT-Wdzu7s1A9CMHYTj0nYLvGlKse71PU3U8LZeMjQa9m9xxl6_Hh4n7oCyTNJRzK4dry83OUkA5jfLpzm1bRUlLWrkG1_l5A-iYd5NlRI-a9CftiQSJdqmvGUPbWfFOUHke0MgeqyDR5Tot7ZDZXJfVFghRhVb77cGOfHqkIxhNjZefwwKIdhVf41lNYb_DYvhajhfyMsZgxJLEWeK6aHNghRQ3vAuQ3XQ-P-pbyIGa1Tfkvwp6SRCMZ6D4Z4pO3H70xUZZuNtDHOlirb6gi4mYSRssTiUg_1r1BdiLLoX9h4tViWJYh8q69S_LNCBO8NBdam4nqFoPJuBaWUC2y1wT2q1IrOzFRzurnCXS46i4-Gzbnx4xzpCFVuvSwKRKp_KZR1n0MPvIpw8zloYUELh3cpzdodMcrYm_sdS3JaK4doxVoZfHWdZQBdQiOm0GQQCoOCcn6Lr3K5X5aZB_D7Gv94zDNJ53ESM7FtK4WPydj6ilA8mfiRD-ISmh28vVDlSHFg59kZ-QVZd0jqpdmkkcFpWSDONZyC3IJCIJLQAZgq-9rXiK1HGkI1ljPkSvDfOHc0N0WdTtxo6OaFdM1OuJ8pqT6ByVsDWlbPxj5fS1vnG1UHubM6aTIiKyAb2UgRphtfauSIebYJHii1ywM-Vngsrb4VZC6Irhgs0GZ5UtibzCK9_z3UcL7mKJLAJr5L69xzOTdvE0m85m7Qay6MlsPL7VQKWEdq5TjOegtxQ3hWaHc7AYDS_MigjhmYvm01_tO3Zexrtbj52OBT-h3xRZawGtjshSh7MqjhJYBll7AYmXU9h_gi01gieEkZndxD3RfdHIzej6elLUsua4x7OvK88IIOlFrf3yCue50p3LgB_NFNFSIo_Dj-jlK5qXm1r9zk6hILZ3ZELTYbG1DgEfzshFDq6y4gCYoK7QTwhs0ou_IQdB133gg0_rGt5tTUvlH6rIn3n9HxzeeUrSXWDPq3AK86IG-dVhZvfWOlOkQllacwlAO7zbyldKbI08vPuEdWVAfTzX1KFFlEyiXH831kyPM2yn-h1JmdVo6ISduwHJO8iJq31mgAE8kkLYetqHHpOpWFhiVWYITQegVtyOJWIUBxhB3okjOyIjNvNaHw48e3XO9iGErUy3RJe_0--UVI1ovJW1FIN7in4Heac_18po8mRAIi6Y7mI3jHL66UGlSAKNipoUNtXxzskOEGyLr2WatcO9jvXhS2r8EB-jX7hTCNUqKj9zcwy77YIlpdxKH_BiTROOhT4p0CuXCfskKhtnMcF1h2nHYvX4sdzG7N2jWofYr7iEQCFvaMmVNf7UGz5a6G7Kkyyur424pSoJPXvA_MVHZa9F0NR26KcktQzsck1tnTFAplW9JLqYeMt3xKJhLTYbD85fXL8htaV38E_Bsq_yadYmYkCD7kO-DCIoyAjuN6v6mkSAemvWoGzktaECHIlhDpGNj9HqlQ1iMFtdxoICAASBORokPRgAQ&xfc=https://adclick.g.doubleclick.net/pcs/click%3Fxai%3DAKAOjstE8NxB_LLXd-cCsaacSaM7uSPZZAT3C3rw050Sv_I8gOl5K47ySZMgKqBMc1RYFH0N_EtFKvx5yCW37isNHZYj1xaF1oe881WCUcxcC1EOu3oSkf2aEqe4LX_5xQejAPQHb73WlznnxYvMMs2DJHopvqbHFOWlfyxH5153QtKH7GQGJNOvPaCGO1172emoD9V9eui-I6Mg_HWTEzep_WDAc_BYRPYzeUvSA_KOBYB_H0fFDrHBn5XUyI7QXEly3WS9glB_E5C8z-foLv8I8HXcp1qwywTPq8P-Jw%26sai%3DAMfl-YQlFpfICcJmlUjVYIGOy6U8IBAzqghnMQh1JPN_vYx7d_MZjIYoE9r245rMxQkAzNGxOnN58J9lEwUnei5_U0xB7tfxXA7_X_g10enTjA%26sig%3DCg0ArKJSzDZ5QRnF_PyqEAE%26urlfix%3D1%26adurl%3D&adsafe_url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F&adsafe_type=e&adsafe_url=https%3A%2F%2Ftpc.googlesyndication.com%2Fsafeframe%2F1-0-35%2Fhtml%2Fcontainer.html&adsafe_type=df&adsafe_jsinfo=,id:1ebba630-2bc8-8aa6-24ea-21572a53c472,c:jtSb9C,sl:outOfView,em:true,fr:false,mn:app29ami,pt:1-5-15,wc:0.23.1920.1010,ac:1261.1091.300.250,am:i,cc:1261.1091.300.250,piv:0,obst:0,th:0,reas:l,br:g,abv:na,an:n,fm:rxkJEa7+11*.292726-36993954|111|12,idMap:11*,pl:,rend:0,renddet:WINDOW,rmeas:0,es:0,sc:1,ha:1,gm:0,tt:rjss,thd:1,et:55,oid:4be7c067-afa3-11e9-938d-382c4ac63135,v:17.4.191,sp:0,wr:1920.1010,sr:1920.1080,ov:0
[HTTP/1.1 302 Found 18ms]

GEThttps://static.adsafeprotected.com/sca.17.4.95.js
[HTTP/1.1 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://static.adsafeprotected.com/sca.17.4.95.js
[HTTP/1.1 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://bid.g.doubleclick.net/xbbe/creative/adj?p=APEucNWxbSLlZpZR_5kk6mld9KwbLbRONvsVLuVvlEB6q-FAVEw5iyQ&d=CkkAoCZ_4I1y4jHgHRtBBwHkQLZGk5W3DR3PFlhbNZHNu0vIWaHtdQMOIuIIfgE5FhAURex1eY1hTNK6iNf5fiGeC222sSsBPUOxEtkQAKAmf-B7geQzcgrbORpj0NUepgNotWMspubeV0xNu-e5QSm_HMKUbA3me_3jJWbAUgiIV28nyWJyc470kkjQNL4-ztqPtB0ZCTaHnk_6LDr-2_BknKWylfkJw-4k7U1d3IwxuZoj3hqoPxX85GMKvPw6o5t6ty4wYNuL1oE4XAB0gKDh3U5yjo8HN7N8LGFNJl57RhtsKk37d0aRt37DZHjWeHeXXvy7FXxczIW_z6VtumJjmvq7Pk_OpjIw92tI7-pZ5bQ99K0oWmHa4S9IFmpYWRB1O_OqieXM9uVdNHwGZKgN8uUHkgjfXHSlzhgyLIXBN0G2Mhjq2FLQHqBcmEpwHZRiPOjJDGNuWUcTMlFgtz4kAZEIZgp5IyvQ9hAzPgdoJhMaVolZSH94S1kKigzKSeSFGoSbtSpuv3pAgNe3f7P0GiS-gpaZKmj85RZLo-nrV6xg2w2Fivj1-QEX69s1M4tcSuetDIhqxotNcjW1zYWgx1kT3pDylHxVITxfnU_aKgYQec72apSPqC1XYJh8mBl82p5GEt-cWrekyJR4MPNqg7AdKTWJ96b_77U8fL2QejIw85XQR2QXjRkNJcrMn3EmeEfByGiNSyOxiIWoU9nnDCtUUzo0WRRXBLYeOBHDCPh654L065gLNt1FBXALQdjc0fUWnElcXi-RRj1oiwj9TUWzmkuZGYpRXhMoRZRMii2uUtqpZC01WIrVPwzP-GdAGoew8KhB1ZsQveHprSxqIq-_9pB_q6lJYVLXameHgaTJLzVaU0dEVVOUNcOkI0VO1k3MWcHZS-Fe0MRYGrDm8ExWX3UgwVndnEMFogBG6FEaZXcOLZArOT5OS-0uzZYsUcDVCOdDW_2Vn2xywkfeTUJXPZSFvek0SA-LNBBiVAy2XvZgh8KD-oLtIJyr3TqCkC0_Fm4rAS0tqjOpkpui_cYZR4z9fmvQelmMv9-rDvFgeAx5zcEuP5QtHKa-nMViwgu08TvTt_e3wQGbadAQYrirIT-aAkYmNhQiuGQiw5x99y2mArxSiQ7oZ4p3RI7UwOEiqNsIOrPeLhcQ4u2ll63ZJeNMfOLVKHQ18OFCaetmuR29x1zk3kdVV5ChAHPw5UO6JLAmP3RasePKLfYREF3eqlijkdpgU2-g42KElQFLTmaVMeZxA32hO0ZfqAVLQQ7ornHNjwqFYoE7__JdHDuluMo1mLJ2ftAer3posWD1lgyKxrWIBaSZptUwHO2LPmUkXNLeRsYl4zwWqsv3rMPhvmllpOMWLefJKMvTBrrXilqeQf3Y1VWztOKO-QG8OkkXq3HZ4bAdiSx0xkiGe6nt4LnhpmqdzmQzZ-8IGrfRuLpgEEhFM0tcUfqyroXT-Wdzu7s1A9CMHYTj0nYLvGlKse71PU3U8LZeMjQa9m9xxl6_Hh4n7oCyTNJRzK4dry83OUkA5jfLpzm1bRUlLWrkG1_l5A-iYd5NlRI-a9CftiQSJdqmvGUPbWfFOUHke0MgeqyDR5Tot7ZDZXJfVFghRhVb77cGOfHqkIxhNjZefwwKIdhVf41lNYb_DYvhajhfyMsZgxJLEWeK6aHNghRQ3vAuQ3XQ-P-pbyIGa1Tfkvwp6SRCMZ6D4Z4pO3H70xUZZuNtDHOlirb6gi4mYSRssTiUg_1r1BdiLLoX9h4tViWJYh8q69S_LNCBO8NBdam4nqFoPJuBaWUC2y1wT2q1IrOzFRzurnCXS46i4-Gzbnx4xzpCFVuvSwKRKp_KZR1n0MPvIpw8zloYUELh3cpzdodMcrYm_sdS3JaK4doxVoZfHWdZQBdQiOm0GQQCoOCcn6Lr3K5X5aZB_D7Gv94zDNJ53ESM7FtK4WPydj6ilA8mfiRD-ISmh28vVDlSHFg59kZ-QVZd0jqpdmkkcFpWSDONZyC3IJCIJLQAZgq-9rXiK1HGkI1ljPkSvDfOHc0N0WdTtxo6OaFdM1OuJ8pqT6ByVsDWlbPxj5fS1vnG1UHubM6aTIiKyAb2UgRphtfauSIebYJHii1ywM-Vngsrb4VZC6Irhgs0GZ5UtibzCK9_z3UcL7mKJLAJr5L69xzOTdvE0m85m7Qay6MlsPL7VQKWEdq5TjOegtxQ3hWaHc7AYDS_MigjhmYvm01_tO3Zexrtbj52OBT-h3xRZawGtjshSh7MqjhJYBll7AYmXU9h_gi01gieEkZndxD3RfdHIzej6elLUsua4x7OvK88IIOlFrf3yCue50p3LgB_NFNFSIo_Dj-jlK5qXm1r9zk6hILZ3ZELTYbG1DgEfzshFDq6y4gCYoK7QTwhs0ou_IQdB133gg0_rGt5tTUvlH6rIn3n9HxzeeUrSXWDPq3AK86IG-dVhZvfWOlOkQllacwlAO7zbyldKbI08vPuEdWVAfTzX1KFFlEyiXH831kyPM2yn-h1JmdVo6ISduwHJO8iJq31mgAE8kkLYetqHHpOpWFhiVWYITQegVtyOJWIUBxhB3okjOyIjNvNaHw48e3XO9iGErUy3RJe_0--UVI1ovJW1FIN7in4Heac_18po8mRAIi6Y7mI3jHL66UGlSAKNipoUNtXxzskOEGyLr2WatcO9jvXhS2r8EB-jX7hTCNUqKj9zcwy77YIlpdxKH_BiTROOhT4p0CuXCfskKhtnMcF1h2nHYvX4sdzG7N2jWofYr7iEQCFvaMmVNf7UGz5a6G7Kkyyur424pSoJPXvA_MVHZa9F0NR26KcktQzsck1tnTFAplW9JLqYeMt3xKJhLTYbD85fXL8htaV38E_Bsq_yadYmYkCD7kO-DCIoyAjuN6v6mkSAemvWoGzktaECHIlhDpGNj9HqlQ1iMFtdxoICAASBORokPRgAQ&xfc=https://adclick.g.doubleclick.net/pcs/click%3Fxai%3DAKAOjstE8NxB_LLXd-cCsaacSaM7uSPZZAT3C3rw050Sv_I8gOl5K47ySZMgKqBMc1RYFH0N_EtFKvx5yCW37isNHZYj1xaF1oe881WCUcxcC1EOu3oSkf2aEqe4LX_5xQejAPQHb73WlznnxYvMMs2DJHopvqbHFOWlfyxH5153QtKH7GQGJNOvPaCGO1172emoD9V9eui-I6Mg_HWTEzep_WDAc_BYRPYzeUvSA_KOBYB_H0fFDrHBn5XUyI7QXEly3WS9glB_E5C8z-foLv8I8HXcp1qwywTPq8P-Jw%26sai%3DAMfl-YQlFpfICcJmlUjVYIGOy6U8IBAzqghnMQh1JPN_vYx7d_MZjIYoE9r245rMxQkAzNGxOnN58J9lEwUnei5_U0xB7tfxXA7_X_g10enTjA%26sig%3DCg0ArKJSzDZ5QRnF_PyqEAE%26urlfix%3D1%26adurl%3D
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 51ms]

GEThttps://ads.everesttech.net/ads/mts/15699/4249?DFA_Click_Tracker=^(t_cq_ue_https://adclick.g.doubleclick.net/pcs/click?xai=AKAOjstE8NxB_LLXd-cCsaacSaM7uSPZZAT3C3rw050Sv_I8gOl5K47ySZMgKqBMc1RYFH0N_EtFKvx5yCW37isNHZYj1xaF1oe881WCUcxcC1EOu3oSkf2aEqe4LX_5xQejAPQHb73WlznnxYvMMs2DJHopvqbHFOWlfyxH5153QtKH7GQGJNOvPaCGO1172emoD9V9eui-I6Mg_HWTEzep_WDAc_BYRPYzeUvSA_KOBYB_H0fFDrHBn5XUyI7QXEly3WS9glB_E5C8z-foLv8I8HXcp1qwywTPq8P-Jw&sai=AMfl-YQlFpfICcJmlUjVYIGOy6U8IBAzqghnMQh1JPN_vYx7d_MZjIYoE9r245rMxQkAzNGxOnN58J9lEwUnei5_U0xB7tfxXA7_X_g10enTjA&sig=Cg0ArKJSzDZ5QRnF_PyqEAE&urlfix=1&adurl=https://adclick.g.doubleclick.net/pcs/click?xai=AKAOjsufx5C3YDi1ScYi4nweVhzZJ4YN-DpI14bsyLYnUDsIDlmXCKx0CB5E7VqvCFKESLRmaWpE5vCjLnBRxvlC3KctpR69uke-YhgD_iQ7II8xWzMWaa5PQfhs-Ud4B_ngOGtwt2s0uVd2_yGuKUqrc2h3uP64wjk24MQmxdNEhvJpdqo5-9J4lRmP9Z0RF059C_nGkO_plJBXX5oepCkC2HTzJxzRdMhaM8DI7EpZNwnqEDzKeBuKmzQfzCOwgMUyxiYnDX7tQk07o8Yq32c5un25H3l6Qgp7_ZSWBHm_d3ye2v6Pah2kHrB_cYQUyQMt9UV--7kRAa7KzojI-gOAEC3uSrDZtgMcomFHpFWos7BZRKTZGjCu4q_cZR-P4gK060tsk-jt35de4pPGXU-YGi482ETU1cAZZ0d-h-69Z59V5eKa9eZSnq4ldZrMxGgzAz3Dd5beU4JOQvksFxvB-XQjxFozU-EDE9bG4FCNyDzmqScCQ61UHL7tAwLZT7VaRcbO1lY6i-cctuAMjLtrmUrKjz5MWpLMwe9g-QE5hCRWZ2bCYQ5lMKmWfvi6WlT0uA7tOLNBDI9cfsoDRSdLj_WgTwbUZbcvKXhnsD8VomoV3JQxWO-VoQSiVSgRMTZxaxwF8yoT7CLr4duz6AVFj076-BDA9Y0t5O9Pr3aq22Bf1FLEDPpuNc9TUPma5NE3G8S0_GH01YRUhbpuNGG8NvQ2hayzRWshC7zjA748RyBr_BvXU2Ro6nfRPkUliV0HPEEH5tioMHT68IG_WIxTqYxSlgUv8ZFtg8xC6hwLbiCESicP4IFmZpNoUoOq2oV3vZIsAQbJlP6GlIlBkwPeUvaIAdKB0PMYvQZ75lJdElQn7FDX3Ohx6KLAvtkVV4XnQY-mx2vw1AthDGUSqH-Zf3CJErPM9OurqxVqm-7J3LGrEyw_rlLfSyW64hK4zG9dv2femBKs3ZlPTwk0o_7inOARK7g3nqcEhZIAGBXPprhr0r2o4hRfW7c2n6m-wdeGmkk6seAbSZsjGqL9wa235t-Uey1V3e1kMc3pLdjr&sai=AMfl-YSoavL6ykNwB88u9i-rRFV01jCLDJafC3wZTqr4TJlRk68VuOh61fQn4Us0tRudUhva1wy6qguORhLc3h5Wtyh38s9lPeLvyP9WTU8jzb8HIeBO13eiY3onPXtXfwYv-vY&sig=Cg0ArKJSzAEA6Qa9EPbAEAE&urlfix=1&adurl=_ue_cq)&DFA_BuyId=22905106&DFA_PlacementId=249663964&DFA_AdId=445913258&DFA_CreativeId=110159679&DFA_SiteId=3654125&TC_1=2000097&TC_2=22905106&TC_3=249663964&TC_4=110159679&ct=NL&st=&city=9977&dma=0&zp=4107&bw=4&DCM_PlacementID=249663964
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 188ms]

GEThttps://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/r20190724/r20110914/abg_lite.js
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/r20190724/r20110914/abg_lite.js
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

a: 1ms - timer gestopt sca.17.4.95.js:32:8009
GEThttps://ads.everesttech.net/ads/mts/15699/4249?DFA_Click_Tracker=https%3A%2F%2Fadclick.g.doubleclick.net%2Fpcs%2Fclick%3Fxai%3DAKAOjstE8NxB_LLXd-cCsaacSaM7uSPZZAT3C3rw050Sv_I8gOl5K47ySZMgKqBMc1RYFH0N_EtFKvx5yCW37isNHZYj1xaF1oe881WCUcxcC1EOu3oSkf2aEqe4LX_5xQejAPQHb73WlznnxYvMMs2DJHopvqbHFOWlfyxH5153QtKH7GQGJNOvPaCGO1172emoD9V9eui-I6Mg_HWTEzep_WDAc_BYRPYzeUvSA_KOBYB_H0fFDrHBn5XUyI7QXEly3WS9glB_E5C8z-foLv8I8HXcp1qwywTPq8P-Jw%26sai%3DAMfl-YQlFpfICcJmlUjVYIGOy6U8IBAzqghnMQh1JPN_vYx7d_MZjIYoE9r245rMxQkAzNGxOnN58J9lEwUnei5_U0xB7tfxXA7_X_g10enTjA%26sig%3DCg0ArKJSzDZ5QRnF_PyqEAE%26urlfix%3D1%26adurl%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fadclick.g.doubleclick.net%2Fpcs%2Fclick%3Fxai%3DAKAOjsufx5C3YDi1ScYi4nweVhzZJ4YN-DpI14bsyLYnUDsIDlmXCKx0CB5E7VqvCFKESLRmaWpE5vCjLnBRxvlC3KctpR69uke-YhgD_iQ7II8xWzMWaa5PQfhs-Ud4B_ngOGtwt2s0uVd2_yGuKUqrc2h3uP64wjk24MQmxdNEhvJpdqo5-9J4lRmP9Z0RF059C_nGkO_plJBXX5oepCkC2HTzJxzRdMhaM8DI7EpZNwnqEDzKeBuKmzQfzCOwgMUyxiYnDX7tQk07o8Yq32c5un25H3l6Qgp7_ZSWBHm_d3ye2v6Pah2kHrB_cYQUyQMt9UV--7kRAa7KzojI-gOAEC3uSrDZtgMcomFHpFWos7BZRKTZGjCu4q_cZR-P4gK060tsk-jt35de4pPGXU-YGi482ETU1cAZZ0d-h-69Z59V5eKa9eZSnq4ldZrMxGgzAz3Dd5beU4JOQvksFxvB-XQjxFozU-EDE9bG4FCNyDzmqScCQ61UHL7tAwLZT7VaRcbO1lY6i-cctuAMjLtrmUrKjz5MWpLMwe9g-QE5hCRWZ2bCYQ5lMKmWfvi6WlT0uA7tOLNBDI9cfsoDRSdLj_WgTwbUZbcvKXhnsD8VomoV3JQxWO-VoQSiVSgRMTZxaxwF8yoT7CLr4duz6AVFj076-BDA9Y0t5O9Pr3aq22Bf1FLEDPpuNc9TUPma5NE3G8S0_GH01YRUhbpuNGG8NvQ2hayzRWshC7zjA748RyBr_BvXU2Ro6nfRPkUliV0HPEEH5tioMHT68IG_WIxTqYxSlgUv8ZFtg8xC6hwLbiCESicP4IFmZpNoUoOq2oV3vZIsAQbJlP6GlIlBkwPeUvaIAdKB0PMYvQZ75lJdElQn7FDX3Ohx6KLAvtkVV4XnQY-mx2vw1AthDGUSqH-Zf3CJErPM9OurqxVqm-7J3LGrEyw_rlLfSyW64hK4zG9dv2femBKs3ZlPTwk0o_7inOARK7g3nqcEhZIAGBXPprhr0r2o4hRfW7c2n6m-wdeGmkk6seAbSZsjGqL9wa235t-Uey1V3e1kMc3pLdjr%26sai%3DAMfl-YSoavL6ykNwB88u9i-rRFV01jCLDJafC3wZTqr4TJlRk68VuOh61fQn4Us0tRudUhva1wy6qguORhLc3h5Wtyh38s9lPeLvyP9WTU8jzb8HIeBO13eiY3onPXtXfwYv-vY%26sig%3DCg0ArKJSzAEA6Qa9EPbAEAE%26urlfix%3D1%26adurl%3D&DFA_BuyId=22905106&DFA_PlacementId=249663964&DFA_AdId=445913258&DFA_CreativeId=110159679&DFA_SiteId=3654125&TC_1=2000097&TC_2=22905106&TC_3=249663964&TC_4=110159679&ct=NL&st=&city=9977&dma=0&zp=4107&bw=4&DCM_PlacementID=249663964&edge=y&html5=y&nr=0.6396539099242701
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 197ms]

GEThttps://dco-assets.everestads.net/ics-campaign/static/dco/html5-ad-script_v3.html?data=XTr1_gAAAiTzEzz5
[HTTP/1.1 200 OK 98ms]

GEThttps://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/pcs/view?xai=AKAOjsuI4T2aaYy8jVZIie-DQGEAS6fD3xnxwNQ60Fgi1f2fTRi2KvPTHtkXmzY2YbMG02BDMkHoEe822b23DoyCtqT1A5_Kojt4v9Z-qrBUZg_v283Ra0TyHUnL2Tox0LHnCI9ncosftzMHgriDorD4wG02DDkzmdnx9Oklwh0QciMdhd0TUrewU62xLtC2HlQBeGe1EhkvVlJ4tCnqn9mlPnI28AOWlduseDUHsxU0IRvBZLWqqY9vlbEHyInmfOIX1qEaQQUtP4Ft9Hc0DCeJ4OxwymKvwYxpkLWt_FGbEw&sai=AMfl-YSaxzv39-mODzRsThLT5MZyosZvQOwxWqR3n7U5OEZN8Ntms_Uw0EyyP2NihxxkTsUKPi1O5odrucJxEHfQt7GnnxH-6PrOyVMjsTfKwQ&sig=Cg0ArKJSzEz2QMNKBfbLEAE&urlfix=1&adurl=
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 20ms]

GEThttps://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/gen_204?id=xbid&dbm_b=AKAmf-DkhabehXCU3bWEbJwIPbJ2Ki9CyrqljZGtL3XsJBMciywpN27k4gz82sUp3-QPbA_Uq5cZMyajitspeNHT_u-QuWA1PP035pc2vv4YQDptc8-RyBM
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 19ms]

GEThttps://tpc.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/r20190724/r20110914/client/window_focus.js
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://tpc.googlesyndication.com/sodar/UFYwWwmt.js
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://dt.adsafeprotected.com/dt?advEntityId=292726&asId=1ebba630-2bc8-8aa6-24ea-21572a53c472&tv={c:jtSbaa,pingTime:-2,time:87,type:a,im:{sf:0,pom:1,prf:{beA:486,beZ:489,mfA:494,cmA:498,inA:498,inZ:511,prA:511,prZ:523,si:541,poA:543,poZ:553,cmZ:553,mfZ:553,loA:566,loZ:570,ltA:571,ltZ:572}},sca:{dfp:{df:0}},env:{gca:0},clog:[{piv:0,vs:o,r:l,w:300,h:250,t:52}],es:0,sc:1,ha:1,gm:0,slTimes:{i:0,o:88,n:0,pp:0,pm:0},slEvents:[{sl:o,t:51,wc:0.23.1920.1010,ac:1261.1091.300.250,am:i,cc:1261.1091.300.250,piv:0,obst:0,th:0,reas:l,bkn:{piv:[71~0],as:[70~300.250]}}],slEventCount:1,em:true,fr:false,e:,tt:rjss,dtt:0,fm:rxkJEa7+11*.292726-36993954|111|12,idMap:11*,rend:0,renddet:WINDOW,rmeas:0,sinceFw:28,readyFired:false}&br=g
[HTTP/1.1 200 OK 457ms]

GEThttps://googleads4.g.doubleclick.net/pcs/view?xai=AKAOjst4WlpWpnV912b5npLvyGxsONPGtfznkca7yJEfKfUJzZxVuRFuGwkzaW_SAD23RIMxqT1XECe-V9VQWBKsiTMWQLqCxb95XxkpBNF_G4Fie-QpdQRkNQBJ&sai=AMfl-YRtdeYdwIASFujennmUs7mb-VBD6RHtjCdDcJ1KOR05kICICnLyWSWhDs5UCiJdC3Rc8ljzihY7u0-C&sig=Cg0ArKJSzOfcNBdn0DeFEAE&urlfix=1&adurl=
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 21ms]

GEThttps://dt.adsafeprotected.com/dt?advEntityId=292726&asId=1ebba630-2bc8-8aa6-24ea-21572a53c472&tv={c:jtSbh6,pingTime:-10,time:517,type:s,mvn:ZnNjPTEyLHNkPTMsbm89Nyxhc3A9MQ--,fsc:17.4.95v222002022000220000022202220000022222200022222200222200002020222002222202202222202222222022220000220000000022222222220222222222222202222222222222222222222222222222222222220000022022020022202222222202202022022222222000000000020222202022222220002220022020020220200000002002022202220000022200202202200022000200222022220220020202220022222202000220020002222222222222202002022002222200000000020200000000000000002220,sd:MTcuNC45NXYxMDEwfHwxOTIwfHwxfHwxfHwyNHx8MTA4MHx8MHx8MHx8MXx8bGFuZHNjYXBlLXByaW1hcnl8fDI0fHwxNi85fHwxNi85fHwwfHwxOTIw,no:MTcuNC45NXZNb3ppbGxhfHxOZXRzY2FwZXx8bnx8Mnx8bnx8MHx8bnx8TWFjSW50ZWx8fEdlY2tvfHwyMDEwMDEwMXx8LTEyMHx8TW96aWxsYS81LjAgKE1hY2ludG9zaDsgSW50ZWwgTWFjIE9TIFggMTAuMTQ7IHJ2OjY4LjApIEdlY2tvLzIwMTAwMTAxIEZpcmVmb3gvNjguMHx8MXx8MXx8bnx8bg--,asp:1564145150605||a1230b09d8f4a6d8601849b890ce4ea0||e9fb3e254fc2aadc88da44f06623e6b5||771d85e61c9e20443eef6e88da3bcb45||e79ac11f39c6b6d2d88d94311775bc4e||d8087046ba56249f34c8db683cfb3bf2||ff092f6731b3610919164db44e8bdbc6||50ad572b6f25fca99339615269589c70||1529428597}
[HTTP/1.1 200 OK 470ms]

GEThttps://ats.everesttech.net/ats/ats?cmd=IMP&impParams=zpJlFTnb3fkbGG%2FxNOYACG6C11MK29m45UVcApSuIALoGj4K7TjwRQjHjaKDtYkKcZivLU9cYmPLAzXa1Le9rMfjwwz3qerSMi4IdwX2qI0pt6ua2WXioFuiaBHqvkS%2FnO6%2BrZWPyRp5SDHZdHWWTC7d4000ilfL9EzSwYNW6gh61B%2F%2BLvGbM%2BVVPUGmSAr4P3QMorzn04ujw9b9Or2MVp2BgoypHij1JEb5%2FfwF3nHM9yKI%2Fq1CebuTUexdEyaALGRwJTkop2pn%2BnZ%2FoGtobJnFLoN3nZihk87HPsidLya7Xf2MvSkT5cPkjRyHpOl3s4tPQ3oxq6ctdCs0gV%2FkUyEKNL6n7sEVBLri3hB9o5PCW4UYHnVusYoY20LIgSUhI%2Bc4tcvKhSGmj%2BwSgQu3uViweiQCMmQm2dARcxfpZLH6pZ755CrPYtPLHmlwr4q9E%2BIl2xQLO8MgFLpQNFqrRJebiWMBecSHc%2Fxfj0zcm7VtMDeQkqpN9WAP8an9yAaHzjlKi9XGALUH4LfZCHTwLwVf34VvZMR7Dm%2FZWf9SDryaqdVKAfNT%2FMbJO5PV2O7atEiXHdXPEWYtowp44EbVLyoErkWlrk8xzCcNH7EfrOTXCz%2FAX9OZblMQMHlsWxCPIs%2BySdtLWfCgeF5tw8HjLcLmfhMi9CV5sndEssoYCTTIvSBvGhg52UI4tOPnaH0cj9oFrFSVBVa61YSysANH2vlqgAmn610DdxcSMb7f86lebxsAh6LUYVc%2F5s4jEvgRzO1%2FilWlb2wriczZ8qkijEpJ6EPMH7bF83w%2BIKCde9jxORxcK4x5IrQI9I9k0znRvEDNqFSetXbyfrqLYf8uQMWgUpzhtD%2FW
[HTTP/1.1 200 OK 954ms]

GEThttps://tpc.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/r20190724/r20110914/client/window_focus.js
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://tpc.googlesyndication.com/sodar/UFYwWwmt.js
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://dco-assets.everestads.net/ics-campaign/static/dco/mraid.js
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 8ms]

GEThttps://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/gen_204?id=sodarir&v=30&d=1&s=1&f=0.01&bgai=B9x2c_fU6Xdz6OImD-gat-L3wBwAAAAA4AeAEAg
[HTTP/2.0 204 No Content 13ms]

GEThttps://tpc.googlesyndication.com/sodar/Enqz_20U.html
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/bg/Zp3MyIPqEN9phDhaazXOScQ7CEAb50E_zMRzm6eiUQg.js
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://dt.adsafeprotected.com/dt?advEntityId=292726&asId=1ebba630-2bc8-8aa6-24ea-21572a53c472&tv={c:jtSbsS,time:1247,type:e,es:0,sc:1,ha:1,gm:0,slTimes:{i:0,o:1247,n:0,pp:0,pm:0},slEvents:[{sl:o,t:51,wc:0.23.1920.1010,ac:1261.1091.300.250,am:i,cc:1261.1091.300.250,piv:0,obst:0,th:0,reas:l,bkn:{piv:[1230~0],as:[1229~300.250]}}],slEventCount:1,em:true,fr:false,e:,tt:rjss,dtt:0,fm:rxkJEa7+11*.292726-36993954|111|12,idMap:11*,rend:1,renddet:XIFRAME.qs.lf,rmeas:1}&br=g
[HTTP/1.1 200 OK 88ms]

GEThttps://dco-assets.everestads.net/ics-campaign//5031/t/7177/5/300x250.html
[HTTP/1.1 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/bg/Zp3MyIPqEN9phDhaazXOScQ7CEAb50E_zMRzm6eiUQg.js
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://code.createjs.com/createjs-2015.11.26.min.js
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://dco-assets.everestads.net/ics-campaign//5031/t/7177/5/300x250.js
[HTTP/1.1 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://ads.everesttech.net/ads/static/local/AMOLibrary.js
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.0.2/TweenMax.min.js
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/gen_204?id=sodar&v=30&t=2&bgai=B9x2c_fU6Xdz6OImD-gat-L3wBwAAAAA4AeAEAg&bg=!4uGl4flEjNSEQfrixWQCAAAAXFIAAAAGCgACoUSZASejpnsU7zUDWW9yt-RUK104ajyrl5jQbwmVugyddvJVV8DJEJ3YiMcJPnlA25FOLArqkybMWBGW_2XlLM0FShm1oIPbXF2OqOMBKoq7Az7YnYWxVADNvmg1jDxMOlbwMNeiS_Of6w_9rcpWWx1pz4lQWfZscC7gQtZ6jnJGw4uKpkRCE_H6YVrJ7Ry8Kzdnh8jPCJYp7zFAcWst_qnLAXhQ7y0H1cklsjjdbcs4ypEZvP4-zeGMVakFsD1KcLCTyyrJFeIx768fWsyw-xQLYtfCgo9aaUDvSnonYgKuHEqUMGJhNnaKTRbwzM3f6fNjojuBhvJxmZav2PogxncHEQfJi8V1iAL3Y3nc7f-dH-7c51gEaxU6Pp3iZ-3ebihNJKcigPFk-Rnc
[HTTP/2.0 204 No Content 15ms]

GEThttps://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.0.2/TweenMax.min.js
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://dco-assets.everestads.net/ics-campaign//5031/t/7177/5/300x250.js
[HTTP/1.1 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://ads.everesttech.net/ads/static/local/AMOLibrary.js
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://assets.everesttech.net/NFL/video_assets/onebyonepixel.png
[HTTP/1.1 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://dco-assets.everestads.net/iCornerStore/source-images/MICROSOFTSTORE/current/6c633683282eff063abdb9424264e336.png
[HTTP/1.1 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://dco-assets.everestads.net/iCornerStore/source-images/MICROSOFTSTORE/current/6c633683282eff063abdb9424264e336.png
[HTTP/1.1 200 OK 0ms]
```

Comment: Doesn't reproduce on chrome 75.0.3770.142 (win10)

Comment: Can't reproduce it either (both SO main and meta work). What happens when you execute `history.back()` in the console?

Comment: I checked on the main site - not meta

Comment: If you paste `javascript:history.back();` into the URL bar and press enter you're technically not using the commandline.

Comment: @ivarni, I read that you need to launch firefox from the commandline to be able to use javascriptcommands on the browserconsole. But I found out I can use the webconsole from the FF dev tools and there is an option to send commands

Comment: @Rob Using `History.back(1)` leads me back to the question list, so the desired behaviour.

Comment: Also I noticed that the edit link on the bottom of a post doesn't end with a `#`, while the close and flag links do.

Comment: @Kaiido I can reproduce here, not even having to edit it again. Having edited it was enough.

Comment: Here, with the link now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56669947/how-to-delete-the-content-of-a-txt-file-with-vba

Comment: And do you have any error in your browser's console? Sounds like the js that should have launched the inline editor didn't kicked in.

Comment: @Kaiido found two things that might possibly be related, see edit I made

Comment: There is this linked question that sounds somewhat similar [Pressing the back button after editing a question only refreshes the edit page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299713/pressing-the-back-button-after-editing-a-question-only-refreshes-the-edit-page)

Answer (score 1):

The problem also occurs when just navigating to a question and waiting for the ads to load. So it looks like the problem is due to one or more ads on the page that somehow add an extra navigation to the page in its history.

I have re-enabled uBlock Origin on Stack Overflow and the problem doesn't occur for me anymore (when opening a question, I haven't verified behaviour on edit).

Specifically for me it happens after the first ad-section below the 'featured'-section is loaded:

[image: Position of slow ad]

As this ad-section happens to load very slow for me (the second ad-section loads faster), the behaviour is erratic and depends on how quick or slow you want to go back. The first ad-section even goes blank again on the first 'back'.

In short, the workaround is to enable your favourite ad-blocker on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I randomly opened a bunch of questions, every time the add you beautifully circled is present this behaviour applies.

Comment: would you care to make a seperate bug report for this. I don't feel editing my question would be appropriate.

Comment: @Luuklag Done: [Returning from question requires to go back twice, ad causing extra (identical) entry in history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387743/returning-from-question-requires-to-go-back-twice-ad-causing-extra-identical)

Comment: Thx, I VTC'd my question as a dupe of yours.