# Returning from question requires to go back twice, ad causing extra (identical) entry in history

Tags: bug, advertising, site-ads, navigation

Since a few days, I notice that returning from a question to the question list occasionally requires having to go back twice. The problem occurs when navigating to a question and waiting for the ads to load, and then going back. It looks like the problem is due to one or more ads on the page that somehow add an extra navigation to the page in its history.

After enabling uBlock Origin on Stack Overflow, the problem doesn't occur for me anymore. Specifically for me it happens after the first ad-slot below the 'featured'-slot is loaded (see circled Microsoft Azure ad):

[image: Position of slow ad]

As this ad-slot happens to load very slow for me (the second ad-slot loads faster), the behaviour is erratic and depends on how quick or slow you want to go back. The first ad-slot even goes blank again on the first 'back'. The second 'back' will take me back to the question list.

I'm using Firefox Quantum 68.0.1 (64 bit) on MacOS.

The workaround is to enable your favourite ad-blocker on Stack Overflow.

This is a follow up to and possibly the same problem as [Having to press the back button twice to go back from a question to the previous page after editing a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387731/having-to-press-the-back-button-twice-to-go-back-from-a-question-to-the-previous)

Comment: As I commented on the answer that Mark gave at my question, I can reproduce this on any question this specific ad loads. Using FF 65.0.2 on MacOS 10.14.5

Comment: @Luuklag I'm not sure if it is only the Microsoft Azure ad that triggers it (although with some tries, it seems to be the only ad I'm getting in that slot right now).

Comment: Same here, might be because of geo-location preferences set on that add. As it is in dutch, and I'm in NL and your profile suggests you are too.

Comment: I just had a question that didn't contain any add, here the problem was not present. Also saw this add on https://stackoverflow.com/ and the problem was present there as well.